# SSH to master node in local IBM Private Cloud cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private

I have installed a local IBM Cloud kubernetes cluster based on this guide:

https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md

and it is up and running successfully. Now I need to SSH to the master node and copy the **configure-registry-cert.sh** file to my host machine, based on:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_1.2.0/manage_images/using_docker_cli.html

But how do I SSH to the master node? From my host machine I have tried with:

```
$ ssh admin@192.168.27.100
```

and specify **admin** as password (I use admin/admin when I login to the webinterface running on: https://192.168.27.100:8443/console) but that does not work.

This page:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/installing/ssh_keys.html

describes that private/public keys needs to be configured during installation but that was never an option. Based on the [vagrant guide](https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md) you just run `vagrant up` and after approx 20 min. everything is up and running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SSH to the master node by  command. You can not use the ICP administrator username and password (e.g.: admin/admin by default) to login to master node, as this username is not the OS user, thanks.

From the 'Deploy IBM Cloud Private beta using Vagrant' link, we can see below commands.

...............

IBM Cloud Private Vagrant Commands

install: vagrant up

stop: vagrant halt (DO NOT USE! USE vagrant suspend TO HALT VM)

start: vagrant up

uninstall: vagrant destroy

***login to master node: vagrant ssh***

suspend: vagrant suspend

resume: vagrant resume

...............

https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md

Comment: Yes that works I missed that part. Now I am trying to find out what the password for the root user so I can login as root and list content in /etc/docker/certs.d based on https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_images/using_docker_cli.html any ideas where to find what root password is?

Answer (score 0):

The simple user is, vagrant / vagrant.
When you perform `vagrant ssh` you will be logged in as **vagrant** user.
To get to root, you can use `sudo su`